# QComboBox Does Not Display Current Text in UI When a Non-Default Value is Selected

Tags: qt, user-interface, uwp, windows-10, qt5

I am developing a UWP application for Windows 10 using Qt for UWP.

One of the UI elements in my application is a QComboBox. The application's logic and the corresponding UI works as expected when the default value (text) is not changed.

However, when I select a different value from the drop-down list, the selected value is not displayed once the drop-down list closes. The box still shows the default value (text). But when I observe the value received by `currentIndex`, it corresponds to the selected value. Whenever I select a non-default value, the UI seems to be blocked. I cannot interact with any other UI elements except the QComboBox element.

Has anyone faced this problem before? How do I ensure that the current selected values is displayed in the QComboBox?

**UPDATE**:

I built a demo application to check the `QComboBox` functionality on its own and I see the same behavior. I just added a few items to the `QComboBox` widget and built the application with both **msvc2017_64** and **winrt_x64_msvc2017** of **Qt 5.14.1**.

When I launch the app that was build using **msvc2017_64**, I get a window with the `QComboBox` widget. When I select a value, that value is displayed when the drop-down menu closes.

However, when this is not the case with the UWP application that I build with **winrt_x64_msvc2017**. It does not show me the updated value. It stays stuck at the default value.

Another problem that I observed in my original UWP app was that whenever I click on the `QComboBox` and select a value, I do not get control of the UI back. Everything in the UI is stuck but whichever button I click is emitting the signal in the background. The UI does not respond at all.

**UPDATE 2**

I was tinkering around trying to understand what was causing this behavior. During this process, I stumbled upon a workaround to get the UI to respond again. If I launch a `QMessageBox` within the `QComboBox`'s `currentTextChanged` signal, I get the UI control back (the `currentText` changes to the value that I previously selected) when I press **OK** on the `QMessageBox` pop-up.

I do not understand why this workaround gives me back control of the UI and gets things working. Please help me understand this.

Comment: How about a [mcve] to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Scheff Since pasting app the files here would be cumbersome, I uploaded to source code to [GitHub](https://github.com/vb0987/QComboBoxDemo). Please open the Visual Studio project file in DemoApplication/uwp/ for the UWP application. Thank you.